# Make mappers process multiple files and not single files

Tags: performance, hadoop, mapreduce

I have a hadoop mapper code that takes file as input processes them and emits the a single key and the processed value to the reducer. The issue is I have close to 100000 text files not more than 5,6 kb but when I run the job, it takes ages to complete. One reason is each mapper is being started to process only one file and then gets destroyed. Thus I am losing lot of time in mapper start up even though the processing is not at all computationally expensive. How do I ensure that mappers continue to process multiple files ?
My maximum limit of the mappers is default setting and I can see that as 6.

Do let me know if any further details are required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the [CombineFileInputFormat](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.2.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/lib/CombineFileInputFormat.html) to process many small files.  This really helps performance.

Comment: I also want to know the file name and when I run the combinerMethod it gives me this error: mapreduce.lib.input.CombineFileSplit cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileSplit